# Equivalent of the idiom "feel free (to do something)"

Tags: traducción, modismos

For instance, If I wanted to say:

> Feel free to contact me

Could I say the following?

> Por favor, contáctame cuando quieras

Does this capture the essence of the idiom, or do any preferable alternatives exist?

Gracias.

Comment: _Allá tú_ is my favorite, only that it has an ironic meaning: yes, do it, but if you fail, get over it! It is what your mum would usually tell you when you ask to do something she doesn't like :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to [Rodrigo's answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/12271/5481), you could use

> Puede contactar con nosotros **con total confianza**

And if you want to go more informal, to use in the context of "feel free to grab a beer" you could use `Puedes [do whatever] cuando quieras` or `si quieres`

> Puedes venir a verme cuando quieras  <sub>feel free to come to see me</sub>
>
> Puedes contactarme cuando quieras  <sub>feel free to contact me whenever</sub>
>
> Puedes coger una cerveza si quieres  <sub>feel free to grab a beer</sub>

And if you want to go more colloquial

> **No te cortes** si quieres coger una cerveza <sub>feel free to grab a beer</sub>

Answer (score 5):

The literal translation is perfectly adequate in any case:

> Siéntete libre de contactarte con nosotros.

But it is more usual to say this:

> No dudes en contactarte con nosotros.

"*No dudar*" literally means *don't hesitate*.

Comment: In Spain, the verb *contactar* would not be pronominal in those cases. But I understand that it is in many American countries.

Comment: @Gorpik What would be used instead?

Comment: Just "contactar": "No dudes en contactar con nosotros".

Comment: Another way that's universally reflexive is *ponerse en contacto con*, YMMV but it feels more natural to me, despite being a bit longer.

Comment: No dudar, I normally translate as "don't hesitate"

Answer (score 1):

Also, the literal translation works in some cases. Only in some cases, mainly informal ones.

For example:

> Queremos que estés como en tu casa, siéntete libre de entrar y salir a cualquier hora.

Means:

> We want you to feel as if you were at your own home, feel free to come and go at anytime.

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking about it I found another possible translation, more related to bussiness work

> Feel free to contact us

To

> Consúltenos sin compromiso

This could be used to make emphasis about contacting a company doesn't tie you to buy any product or service.